# Oracle sql inner join on dates range

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to write join that joins on ids and date range:

```
SELECT * FROM C_INVOICE CI 
INNER JOIN C_CONVERSION_RATE CCR 
    ON CCR.C_CURRENCY_ID=CI.C_CURRENCY_ID 
    AND CI.DATEINVOICED BETWEEN CCR.VALIDFROM AND CCR.VALIDTO
```

But the result I am getting is join from only from

```
ON CCR.C_CURRENCY_ID=CI.C_CURRENCY_ID
```

IN theory this should work just fine, and I don't get any errors, but result is not what I want

#### EDIT

```
--Full query
SELECT * FROM C_INVOICE CI 
INNER JOIN C_CONVERSION_RATE CCR 
    ON CCR.C_CURRENCY_ID=CI.C_CURRENCY_ID 
    AND CI.DATEINVOICED BETWEEN CCR.VALIDFROM AND CCR.VALIDTO
WHERE CI.C_INVOICE_ID='1019748';
```

CI.DATEINVOICED = 15-FEB-16 
CI.C_CURRENCY_ID = 100

There are many rows inside C_CONVERSION_RATE table with C_CURRENCY_ID = 100
but only one row falls into interval.

```
CI.DATEINVOICED(15-FEB-16) BETWEEN CCR.VALIDFROM(15-FEB-16) AND CCR.VALIDTO(15-FEB-16)
```

In this specific case CCR.VALIDFROM, CCR.VALIDTO are both equal to same date 15-FEB-16 but in other cases it can be few days interval

Anyway, the result I am expecting is single row where currency id and date interval matches. However, I am getting all the rows where currency id matches.

#### EDIT

Modified query a bit

```
SELECT 
ci.dateinvoiced,
ccr.validfrom,
ccr.validto
FROM C_INVOICE CI 
INNER JOIN C_CONVERSION_RATE CCR 
    ON CCR.C_CURRENCY_ID=CI.C_CURRENCY_ID 
    AND CI.DATEINVOICED BETWEEN CCR.VALIDFROM AND CCR.VALIDTO
WHERE CI.C_INVOICE_ID='1019748';
```

the result from this query I am getting

```
    15-FEB-16   07-MAR-11   29-JAN-56
    15-FEB-16   02-MAR-11   29-JAN-56
    15-FEB-16   27-MAR-11   29-JAN-56
    15-FEB-16   07-FEB-11   29-JAN-56
    15-FEB-16   18-JAN-12   29-JAN-56
```

ccr.validto seem to be way off 29-JAN-56 there no such date in that column
don't know what causing this problem

Comment: `CI.DATEINVOICED BETWEEN CCR.VALIDFROM AND CI.DATEINVOICED` is always TRUE, same column twice...

Comment: sorry mistake while typing, I edited question now

Comment: So you mean you get rows where the `BETWEEN` condition isn't  `TRUE`?

Comment: Can you please show some examples of incorrect data that you're receiving? Also, please make sure that the query that you're using is what you have posted here.

Comment: jarlh - to answer your question -yes

Comment: @sepikas-antanas Please post some example tables & data (DDL and DML statements) which illustrates the problem.

Comment: The year 16 is between 11/12 and 56.

Comment: When you select validto from the table, the date is different? or its 56 ?

Comment: If you think there is no date with 29-JAN-56 then you might find it useful to use a four-digit-year mask; maybe it isn't in the century you expect, or you're query is only looking at 0056 (depending on your NLS settings). Look for that date, and/or repeat your query with 4-digit years and see what that shows. It would be helpful to show the raw data you're querying against, again with dates showing the full year (and time if any are not 00:00).

Comment: Try `SELECT TO_CHAR( validto, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) FROM C_CONVERSION_RATE WHERE TO_CHAR( validto, 'YY' ) = '56';`

Comment: MT0, I think he needs to select TO_CHAR( <value>, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) for all columns and compare this dates

Comment: @SkyWalker - no, The OP's query should work. All that needs to be done is identify the rows in `C_CONVERSION_RATE` that are appearing unexpectedly and then to make sure they are actually valid/expected data (i.e. there is not some issue being caused by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` being `DD-MON-YY`).

Comment: @sepikas-antanas What are the datataype of the `ci.dateinvoiced`, `ccr.validfrom` and `ccr.validto` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your C_CONVERSION_RATE table contains many rows with a VALIDTO date representative of an arbitrary end-of-time value of 29-JAN-59 (century unknown).  If you are looking for the most recently valid conversion rate relative to the DATEINVOICED, you may need to use an analytic function to determine the next valid VALIDFROM value:

```
WITH CCR AS (
  SELECT CCR.*
       , LEAD(CCR.VALIDFROM,1,CCR.VALIDTO) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY CCR.C_CURRENCY_ID 
                   ORDER BY CCR.VALIDFROM
                          , CCR.VALIDTO
         ) VALID_TO  -- note the underscore ;)
    FROM C_CONVERSION_RATE CCR
)
SELECT *
  FROM C_INVOICE CI 
 INNER JOIN CCR 
    ON CCR.C_CURRENCY_ID=CI.C_CURRENCY_ID 
   AND CI.DATEINVOICED BETWEEN CCR.VALIDFROM AND CCR.VALID_TO -- note the underscore
   AND CI.DATEINVOICED <> CCR.VALID_TO -- Make it a half open interval by not
                                       -- including the exact end date since
                                       -- it is actually the next start date.
```